# iPad Pro 12"9 simulator with wrong resolution?

Tags: xcode, ipad, simulator

I have ensured that I'm using the latest version of Xcode, but when launch my iPad Pro 12"9 simulator (full screen, 100% scale) and programatically get the width and height of the screen, I get `1024x768`. Shouldn't it be `1366x1024` instead? What could cause this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iPad Pro 12.9-inch has a Display Zoom feature that turns the screen into a 2048 x 1536 screen (that's pixels; it's double-resolution, so points would be 1024x768, which is what you are seeing). In effect, it now thinks it's an iPad Air.

So, your iPad Pro is displaying your app in that mode. This could be because:

a. Your iPad Pro really is in Zoomed mode.

b. You failed to include in your app bundle a proper *LaunchScreen.storyboard*.

Comment: Ok I see now, this happened because I did not include a _LaunchScreen.storyboard_ in the bundle. So, just to make sure, this (getting a logical resolution of 1024x768 without the _LaunchScreen.storyboard_) will happen both with the simulator and with a real iPad Pro 12.9" device, that's right? And thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: Correct, and so too for any device that has a Zoomed display mode.